# Error in setting popover content

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I have a function to generate data-content for bootstrap popover from Json .
The problem with the function is that, if I pass json object in which a member contains a single quote then the popover content is not set.

```
function setupopoverContent(content) {
        var json = JSON.parse(content);
        var contents = '<div style="">'
        contents += '<div id="hellobar" class="large right  remains_at_top row-fluid" style="background-color: ' + json.BarColor + '; color: ' + json.TextColor + '; border-radius: 5px;font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"> ';
        contents += '<div id="hb_msg_container" class="span11"> <span id = "topbar_message" style="padding-bottom:14px;">   ';
        contents += HtmlEncode(json.Message); 
        contents += '</span> ';
        contents += '<a id = "topbar_linktext" class="hellobar_cta hb-button" href= "' + json.LinkURL + '" target="_blank" style="color: ' + json.ButtonTextColor + '; background-color: ' + json.ButtonColor + '; border-color: #000000">   ';
        contents += HtmlEncode(json.LinkText);
        contents += '</a></div> ';
        contents += '</div></div>';
        return contents;
    }
```

Suppose that json.Message=All go'es here, then the popover content is not set.
How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried omitting `HtmlEncode`?

http://jsfiddle.net/z6gnpnr5/

Comment: i have ....What i need is to render the string(contents) as html , so i can set it as popover data content.